# Filename too long in Git for Windows

Tags: windows, git

I'm using `Git-1.9.0-preview20140217` for Windows. As I know, this release should fix the issue with too long filenames. But not for me.

Surely I'm doing something wrong: I did `git config core.longpaths true` and `git add .` and then `git commit`. Everything went well. But when I now do a `git status`, I get a list of files with `Filename too long`, for example:

> `node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/integration/test-handle-source-errors.js: Filename too long`

It is quite simple to reproduce for me: just create a [Yeoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeoman_(software)) web application with the Angular generator ("yo angular") and remove `node_modules` from the `.gitignore` file. Then repeat the aforementioned Git commands.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where do you read that that version should fix the long filenames?

Comment: Here is the pull request for the patch: https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/122

Comment: @v.karbovnichy please read my question carefully. I already ran the command in the top voted answer. But at the time I asked the question, the accepted answer was correct: msys still had this character-limitation. Now that limitation is gone and git config core.longpaths true works like it should.

Comment: Ok, I agree then

Comment: Nowadays there is Linux in Windows in form of WSL2. No restrictions added.

Comment: Why would you want to include the content of node_modules in a repo?

Answer (score 2114, accepted):

Git has a limit of 4096 characters for a filename, except on Windows when Git is compiled with msys. It uses an older version of the Windows API and there's a limit of 260 characters for a filename.

So as far as I understand this, it's a limitation of msys and not of Git. You can read the details here:
https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/110

You can circumvent this by using another Git client on Windows or set `core.longpaths` to `true` as explained in other answers.

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Git is build as a combination of scripts and compiled code. With the above change some of the scripts might fail. That's the reason for core.longpaths not to be enabled by default.

The windows documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later has some more information:

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been
> removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you
> must opt-in to the new behavior.
>
> A registry key allows you to enable or disable the new long path
> behavior. To enable long path behavior set the registry key at
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled
> (Type: REG_DWORD)

Comment: As I understand this incorporated pull request (https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/122) it should be fixed now.

Comment: Well yes and no. Read the part in config.txt here: https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/122/files

My advice, don't enable this.

Your problem with git status could be one of the "few quirks" warned about.

Comment: The limitation to 260 chars in a path is not specific to MSYS, it's a general Windows API imitation. This can be worked around by using Unicode paths, but that has other drawbacks, which is why `core.longpaths` is not enabled by default. Also note that Git for Windows it not compiled against MSYS. Instead, it's a native Windows application that comes with a stripped-down MSYS environment.

Comment: @sschuberth: Are there any drawbacks other than lack of compatibility with programs that do not support long paths?

Comment: @JAB Another drawback is that long paths always have to be absolute; relative paths are not supported. For further details please see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#maxpath).

Comment: Or as a quick fix, just try checkout your repo to C:/ on windows thus reducing number of folder path characters.

Comment: As of Windows 10, you can edit your registry (or apply a group policy) to remove the Windows API filename length restriction. https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Comment: Thank you really much! changing register and git config finally worked!

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it keeps saying "error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied"

Comment: @Patlatus I think you need to run it as administrator

Comment: @iveqy Thanks a lot for this
NOTE: use this with cmd (Run as Admin) to avoid other errors

Comment: locally '--system' threw a permissions issue (error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied) so running without '--system' parameter had the desired effect, thanks :)

Comment: Note that if you do not have full admin on your machine you can not edit the global gitconfig with  

    git config --system core.longpaths true

so instead edit your personal .gitconfig and add in  

    [core]

   longpaths = true

(Can't get this to format???)

Comment: This worked for me git config --system core.longpaths true
But remember to open your terminal as administrator,  othercase you  will receive a Permission denied error message

Comment: What if it happens in Linux? Funny as the same works on Windows out of the box.

Comment: @ sschuberth Did you mean UNC paths? Unicode paths is slightly a different thing. With the UNC paths (ex: `\\?\c:\path-longer-than-260`) it does work in Windows 7.

Comment: Solved for me, but I used `--global` instead of `--system` to avoid the need for admin priviliges.

Comment: Don't forget to run powershell as admin

Comment: @jameslafferty Do I still need to run the `git config` command when I change the registry? And/or vice versa? That's what I don't get. I've changed the registry, but I'm still getting the error. So I'm assuming I need to do both? Cheers

Comment: This command `git config --system core.longpaths true`  worked perfectly. For running this command need to open `git cmd` as an `administration` access and run in `Windows 10`. Thanks for help @iveqy

Comment: In case someone had a similar situation like me - I  was using github desktop when I ran across this (or something like this anyway). Using the command 'git config --system core.longpaths true' resulted in getting a different error. The "trick" was to use a console, not gui. Hope this helps someone

Comment: git config core.longpaths true worked for me :)

Comment: I came from [LF will be replaced by CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1967370/496176) issue, commit worked after `git config core.autocrlf false` and `git config --system core.longpaths true`  commands.

Answer (score 1286):

You should be able to run the command

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

from an Administrator command prompt.

Or add it to one of your Git configuration files manually to turn this functionality on, once you are on a supported version of Git. It looks like maybe 1.9.0 and after.

Comment: This config option fixed the issue for me, even with msys as mentioned in the accepted answer. (Specifically, version 1.9.4.msysgit.2).

Comment: Sourcetree acts a bit weird unless you "also make sure that SourceTree is using the System’s Git and not the embedded one." - Thanks to [Matej Drolc](http://pingec.si/blog/articles/msysgit-longpath/) for that advice

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Git-cannot-create-a-file-or-directory-with-a-long-path) is some background information why this is not enabled by default, and some technical details.

Comment: @mcsullivan-dander: in my question, I mentioned that I already did `core.longpath true`. At that time, it did not run out of the box. So I think the accepted answer is right for the context.

Comment: get "could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig" after running command above. But @Yash answer worked for me

Comment: @divideByZero running git bash as administrator prevents that error.

Comment: this worked for me in windows: run git bash as admin, git config --system core.longpaths true, git clone https://yourrepo.git

Comment: I would use `git config --global core.longpaths=true` to enable survival after a git update.

Comment: Windows 10 update 1607 and later now support a registry key which will [remove the MAX_PATH limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) across the entire system.  The registry key is HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled and it should be a DWORD set to 1.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it keeps saying "error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied"

Comment: I only was able to do so after I installed Git for Windows. Any other Registry modifications did not help

Comment: I started the prompt command as Administrator and the command was successfully executed.

Comment: Regarding problems with SourceTree, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996479/naming-convention-for-visual-studio-solutions-and-projects/71279688#71279688

Comment: `could not lock config file c:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig: permission denied`

Comment: immediately solved the issue

Answer (score 375):

This might help:

```
git config core.longpaths true
```

Basic explanation: This answer suggests not to have such setting applied to the global system (to all projects so avoiding `--system` or `--global` tag) configurations. This command only solves the problem by being specific to the current project.

**EDIT:**

This is an important answer related to the "permission denied" issue for those whom does not granted to change git settings globally.

Comment: Folks here have noted that this setting can introduce some unpredictable behavior so it seems that it's preferable to use the above command as a local setting on projects where that require it rather than appending `--system` which will apply it to all projects

Comment: hey, that's just a copypasta of the other highly upvoted answer. might at the very least explain why you prefer removing the --system option..

Comment: I didn't have elevated rights and thus this was much easier to do inside the git repository than to ask the IT team to run the global command with elevated rights. Thanks Sagiruddin!

Comment: Thank you. I got permission denied and your answer solved my issue

Comment: @GrantHumphries what "unpredictable behavior" are you referring to? I found the --global flag was what worked for me, and I want to know what to look out for.

Answer (score 251):

## Steps to follow (Windows):

1. Run **Git Bash** as **administrator** (right-clicking the app shortcut will show the option to `Run as Administrator` )
2. Run the following command:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

**Note**: if step 2 does not work or gives any error, you can also try running this command:

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

Read more about `git config` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Using --global command solved the issue for me!

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second command actually helped me out; Because it was throwing an error by saying "Permission denied".

Comment: git config --global core.longpaths true
, this command solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 136):

Create .gitconfig and add

```
[core]
longpaths = true
```

You can create the file in a project location (not sure) and also in the global location. In my case the location is `C:\Users\{name}\`.

Comment: You can also do this with the following command:
`git config --global core.longpaths true`

Comment: git config --global core.longpaths true worked for me thanks

Comment: Using Visual Studio the git bash solutions above did not work for me, but finding the .git/config file for the project and editing as shown above did. Thanks yash.

Comment: this worked for me, i located that file and modified it manually

Comment: The above mentioned and verified answers are correct but with the permissions which is granted to the file, it might not be possible to update the file with those commands.

This approach is really easy because this is the manual approach and it worked for me really well. You can easily find the `.gitconfig` file in the following path `C:\Users\{username}` and simply edit it.

Comment: this one is the convenient solution than using the command prompt that requires me permissions

Comment: In my case, the config file already existed and I found it here: `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig`.

Answer (score 64):

To be entirely sure that it takes effect immediately after the repository is initialized, but before the remote history is fetched or any files checked out, it is safer to use it this way:

```
git clone -c core.longpaths=true <repo-url>
```

> -c key=value
>
> Set a configuration variable in the newly-created repository; this takes effect immediately after the repository is initialized, but
>   before the remote history is fetched or any files checked out. The key
>   is in the same format as expected by git-config[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone--cltkeygtltvaluegt) (e.g.,
>   core.eol=true). If multiple values are given for the same key, each
>   value will be written to the config file. This makes it safe, for
>   example, to add additional fetch refspecs to the origin remote.

[More info](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone--cltkeygtltvaluegt)

Answer (score 41):

This worked for me

[image: terminal image]

Run as terminal as **administrator**. And run the command below.

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Answer (score 39):

The better solution is enable the longpath parameter from Git.

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

But a workaround that works is remove the node_modules folder from Git:

```
$ git rm -r --cached node_modules
$ vi .gitignore
```

Add node_modules in a new row inside the .gitignore file. After doing this, push your modifications:

```
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m "node_modules removed"
$ git push
```

Comment: There's a good reason to keep the node_modules folder checked into git: If you want your software to behave the same after a year of modules potentially vanishing from npm.

Comment: @cfstras if some library has a vulnerabily and you don't update periodically, certainly you'll have security problems.

Comment: Of course you have to upgrade your dependencies. But only when _you_ want to, and if something were to break, you would want your backup in git...

Comment: Is true. I'll edit my anwser. Thank you for you comment.

Comment: No need to commit `node_modules`: the `packages.lock`file is here to ensure the version installed by `npm install`will always be the same, until you make a `npm update`

Answer (score 36):

Executing `git config --system core.longpaths true` thrown an error to me:

> "error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\mingw32/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied"

Fixed with executing the command at the global level:

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

Comment: The global settings affect only the current user, whereas system settings affect all the users on the machine. If this is your workstation they're effectively the same as you may use only one user.

Comment: If you're command line application Ran as Administrator, first command would work!

Answer (score 21):

- Download & Install Git bash from here: https://git-scm.com/download/win
- Run the git bash gui as administrator and run this command: `git config --system core.longpaths true`
- Now clone any repository.
- If the problem is not fixed try this command: `git config --global core.longpaths true`
- If it does not help try restarting the windows.

Answer (score 18):

You could also try to enable long file paths.

If you run Windows 10 Home Edition you could change your Registry to enable long paths.

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` in `regedit` and then set `LongPathsEnabled` to `1`.

If you have Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise you could also use Local Group Policies.

Go to *Computer Configuration* → *Administrative Templates* → *System* → *Filesystem* in `gpedit.msc`, open *Enable Win32 long paths* and set it to *Enabled*.

Comment: I believe this must be done in combination with the git config, and it's worth noting it doesn't work with Windows Explorer for the reasons mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/1114683/103148).

Comment: Win32 - I wonder if this can help if the application is 64bit?

Answer (score 18):

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

The above command worked for me. Using '--system' gave me config file not locked error

Comment: for Github Desktop users, this is the only one that works because Github Desktop uses its own Git config.

Answer (score 14):

### **TortoiseGit** (Windows)

For anyone using TortoiseGit for Windows, I did this:

(1) Right-click on the folder containing your project.  Select TortoiseGit -> Settings.

(2) On the "Git" tab, click the button to "Edit local .git/config".

(3) In the text file that pops up, under the [core] section, add:
longpaths = true

Save and close everything, then re-try your commit.  For me, this worked.[image]

I hope this minimizes any possible system-wide issues, since we are not editing the global .gitconfig file, but rather just the one for this particular repository.

Answer (score 8):

## Move repository to root of your drive (temporary fix)

You can try to temporarily move the local repository (the entire folder) to the root of your drive or as close to the root as possible.

Since the path is smaller at the root of the drive, it sometimes fixes the issues.

On Windows, I'd move this to `C:\` or another drive's root.

Comment: This is the only thing that solved my issue.  It was that I had too many folders in the path.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows, you can follow these steps which worked for me.

1. Open your cmd or git bash as an administrator

[image]

2. Give the following command either from cmd or git bash which you ran above as an administrator

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

3. This will allow accessing long paths globally
4. And now you can clone the repository with no issues with long paths

Answer (score 3):

### In a windows Machine

Run Command Prompt as administrator then run below command

> git config --system core.longpaths true

Answer (score 2):

I had this error too, but in my case the cause was using an outdated version of npm, v1.4.28.

Updating to npm v3 followed by

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm -i
```

worked for me. npm issue 2697 has details of the "maximally flat" folder structure included in npm v3 (released 2015-06-25).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with your encrypted partition, consider moving the folder to an unencrypted partition, for example a **/tmp**, running `git pull`, and then moving back.

Comment: Could you explain it in detail