# Max length of git branch name

Tags: git, github

I want to understand what is maximum allowed size of a git branch name.

I am trying to create some long names (as an experiment) so a name with 370 characters was valid, but 380 characters gave me `fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: File name too long`

So the questions are: what is the maximum number of characters that can be in git branch name? Does it depend on the system? Is it possible to create long branch name in a repository that will be rejected on remote repository (i.e. Github)?

Comment: There is also some very strange behaviour in this area.  If I try 400 chrs it fails.  If I then try 300 it passes.  Fair enough.  But after the 300 worked I then able to create branches with 400,500,600, etc. chrs.  trying to test and determine the limit at the command line revealed this behavior.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The 'File name too long' is indeed an error coming from your system. It is not a restriction in Git. I don't think there's a way of testing the maximum branch name lengths of other systems, like GitHub's, without experimenting - although I don't see why you would want to know...

.

*Source: the error mentioned is thrown on line 291 of `branch.c`. "File name too long" is the standard description for the ENAMETOOLONG error.*

Comment: I think *some limit* is useful to know, when [GitHub Flow document encourages to use descriptive names.](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html)

Comment: GItHub limit branch names to 255 chars.

Comment: @iconoclast : because it’s not documented.

Comment: @user2284570 Where did you see the limit of 255 chars referenced in GitHub's documentation regarding the length of branch names?

Comment: @mljrg Git branches are stored as filenames. And as Github uses ext4 to store it user s repositories, the branch name limit is the one of the host filesystem which is 255 characters in the case of ext4. Though I got this knowlwedge through [leaks](https://bounty.github.com/researchers/ytrezq).

Comment: @user2284570 Thanks

Comment: Note: Github's branch name limit is 244 characters because they count `refs/heads/` in the name: ```remote: error: GH005: Sorry, refs longer than 255 bytes are not allowed.
remote: ref too long: "refs/heads/Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-elit-Sed-faucibus-et-orci-nec-suscipit-Donec-a-porttitor-sem-porta-laoreet-arcu-Donec-commodo-imperdiet-hendrerit-Morbi-dictum-sit-amet-est-eu-pharetra-Proin-dapibus-ligula-sit-amet-elementum-blandit"```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the accepted answer the practical limit is going to be dependent on components other than git such as the filesystem and remote hosts. GitHub appears to reject all branch names [longer than 244 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66514473/113632). Other git hosts might have different limits, but in practice branch names larger than what GitHub would accept will be a problem for most usages (i.e. it would prevent migrating to GitHub in the future, even if you used a different host today).

Locally (on Ubuntu with ext4) I hit a filesystem error at 251 bytes, because git can't create a `[branchname].lock` file (as this name exceeds 255 bytes):

```
$ git branch $(printf 'n%.0s' {1..251})
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn': Unable to create '/tmp/foo/.git/refs/heads/nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.lock': File name too long
```

However git itself seems happy with far longer branch names, as long as you work around filesystem length limits by including `/`es in the branch name:

```
$ git branch $(printf 'm%.0s' {1..250})/$(printf 'm%.0s' {1..250})
# success
```

So if you're creating branches (on ext4) that you never intend to publish you can make them just about as long as you'd like as long as you structure them like a directory hierarchy.

Answer (score -3):

Open the Github Powershell, and execute the following command :

`git config --system core.longpaths true`

Comment: ^--- this is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows).  Apparently it's a Windows filename (incl. path) length limitation, and the _longpaths_ thing is a way to avoid it (provided you have the right version of Git client).  That question is from 2014, so by now it might be a non-issue.  (BTW, somebody there mentioned git had a filename limit of 4096 chars.)  At any rate, OP asked about _branch_ name length, not filenames.