# What is the maximum length of a Github branch name

Tags: github

I could not find any documentation on what the maximum length of a Github (not Git) branch name is. So, what is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Answer:** 62-250 characters

**Explanation:**
The most technically correct answer is **250 bytes**. To arrive at this conclusion, I just brute forced branch names of various lengths and characters to figure out what the Github limit is. When using a string composed of purely valid ASCII character, the limit is 250 characters which totals 250 bytes if we assume UTF-8 encoding is being used. When using all 32-bit/4-byte Unicode characters (all  characters in my test), the limit is 62 characters which totals 238 bytes. While I didn't test it explicitly, I think it's safe to assume the same rules apply to any arbitrary mix of characters - total bytes being the constraint, not character count.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer; it's easy to test that GitHub rejects 250-byte branch names. 244 bytes, as reported by Rob, appears to be the correct limit.

Answer (score 3):

According to this error message returned by GitHub it is 255 bytes:

```
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 292 bytes | 292.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
remote: error: GH005: Sorry, refs longer than 255 bytes are not allowed.
remote: ref too long: "refs/heads/..."
```

The maximum length holds for whole `ref`, so including "refs/heads/".
You can verify this by creating a branch of 244 ASCII characters and pushing it to GitHub:

```
git checkout -b 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
git push --set-upstream origin 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
```

If you append a single ASCII character to the branch name above the push to GitHub will fail.

Note that the limit is bytes, not characters (Unicode characters can take up multiple bytes).

Comment: It should be noted that the branch name above is 244 characters, not 243 as originally mentioned. The rest of the answer is correct (at this point) that the limit is 255 - len("refs/heads/").

Comment: How about repo name length limit?