# Jenkins Windows Slave ignoring local Git settings

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

I've setup a Windows Jenkins slave to a Unix Jenkins master. I'm running Windows 8.1 with msysgit 1.9.5 and Jenkins 1.616.

When checking out a repository with path/filename longer than 255 characters, I get the "Filename too long" error. This is [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26111092/1257145) by setting `core.longpaths` to true in the git settings. However the Windows Jenkins slave is ignoring the custom settings and uses standard settings.

**What I've tried**

- Setting `core.longpaths` on the Windows Jenkins slave in global, system, local settings:

  ```
  git config --global core.longpaths true
  git config --system core.longpaths true
  git config --local core.longpaths true
  ```
- Setting `core.longpaths` on the Unix Jenkins Master

**The result**

The Windows Jenkins slave is still running git with default settings. I've made a simple build task with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" config -l
```

which yields

```
Started by user mles
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on jw10 in workspace D:\workspace\windowstesting
[windowstesting] $ sh -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson2817786906482449008.sh
+ 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe' config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
Finished: SUCCESS
```

note no `core.longpaths=true`. On the Windows Jenkins slave `core.longpaths=true` is set

```
C:\Users\jw>git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.longpaths=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
```

**What works**

Cloning a repository with very long path/filenames *locally* on the Windows Jenkins slave *without* Jenkins.

[image]

**What does not work**

Cloning the same repository with very long path/filenames on the Windows Jenkins slave *with* Jenkins

```
    Started by user mles
    [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
    Building remotely on jw10 in workspace D:\workspace\windowstesting
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository https://github.com/axelhodler/longfile.git
     > git init D:\workspace\windowstesting # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/axelhodler/longfile.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
     > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/axelhodler/longfile.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
     > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/axelhodler/longfile.git # timeout=10
     > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
     > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/axelhodler/longfile.git # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/axelhodler/longfile.git
     > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/axelhodler/longfile.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
     > git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
     > git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
    Checking out Revision 31b408748324aa6f361828e45ae1d374c3f0fc25 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
     > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     > git checkout -f 31b408748324aa6f361828e45ae1d374c3f0fc25
    FATAL: Could not checkout null with start point 31b408748324aa6f361828e45ae1d374c3f0fc25
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout null with start point 31b408748324aa6f361828e45ae1d374c3f0fc25
       ...
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f 31b408748324aa6f361828e45ae1d374c3f0fc25" returned status code 128:
    stdout: 
    stderr: fatal: cannot create directory at 'launchpad/projects/configurationAdminManager/gofer-configurationAdminManager-notification/src/com/mwaysolutions/gofer2/configurationAdminManager/notification/dummydummy/dummydummy/dummydummy/dummydummy/dummydummy/dummydummy': Filename too long
       ....
    Finished: FAILURE
```

I can not add another build step at the beginning to set `core.longpaths`, as checking out the repository is the first thing jenkins does before running any build steps.

Any ideas why custom settings are ignored by my Windows Jenkins slave?

Comment: I suspect the Jenkins slave is not running as user "jw". If it's a service, it might be running as system user. You can change the service to run as dedicated user "jw".

Comment: You suspected right. Add this as a regular answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins slave should be running as user `jw`. This will make git pick up all the settings you put in for this user.
If running as a service, update the service to run as user `jw` and not as system user.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the user that the Jenkins slave is running as, you can get it configured directly.

- Set up a Jenkins Multi-configuration project called something like JenkinsSlaveScripts under an appropriate 'Admin' view
- I use matrix based security to ensure my regular Jenkins users won't run it
- Configure the axis to run on all your Windows slaves
- Add an "Execute Windows batch script" task

Add the script to be (something like)

```
cd c:\dev-software\git-2.7.1\bin
git config --global core.longpaths true
git config --system core.longpaths true
git config --local core.longpaths true
echo %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig on %COMPUTERNAME%
type %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig
```

When it runs it should update the config of the slaves no matter who they are running as

Comment: This should be the answer, thank you so much for your response! Have an upvote

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked in my case:

1. Go to git installation folder,
2. then edit Git\etc\gitconfig
3. Be sure it contains

   [core]
   longpaths = true

example:

```
[http]
    sslBackend = schannel
[diff "astextplain"]
    textconv = astextplain
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    fscache = true
    symlinks = false
    longpaths = true
[pull]
    rebase = true
```