# Git 'filename too long' error on OS X

Tags: git, macos, filenames, long-filenames, short-filenames

I have a directory that is tracked by `git` on linux and I copied it to mac OS.  On `git status` multiple files are untracked because of a `filename: File name too long` error.  One filename (with its relative path) is 393 characters.  Isn't there a limit 4096 characters (except on Windows)? [[Reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows/22575737#22575737)  My `core.longpaths` setting is set to true.  (Also so is `core.precomposeunicode` set to true, but probably irrelevant).  Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X has `NAME_MAX` (bytes in a path name component) set to 255:

```
$ grep NAME_MAX /usr/include/sys/syslimits.h
#define NAME_MAX          255   /* max bytes in a file name */
#define CHARCLASS_NAME_MAX     14   /* max character class name size */
```

Is that 393 byte name a single component, or the entire path?  (Example: `"foo/bar/baz"` has 3 components that are each 3 bytes, and the entire path is 11 or 12 bytes depending on whether you count the terminating `'\0'`.  The `NAME_MAX` constant here does not count a terminating `'\0'`.)

Answer (score 0):

Other option is change symlink configuration for your project, and you don't need change system vars.

Use the console and use this commands:

- git clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git
- cd xxx
- git config --list
- git config core.symlinks ***false***
- git checkout master
- git pull origin master

### ***I take the answer from:***

> https://github.com/Urigo/IonicCLI-Meteor-WhatsApp/issues/4#issuecomment-382957742