# For the Jenkins git plugin, where is it recommended to run `git config`?

Tags: git, jenkins

Under Jenkins I am having the same `longpaths` issue described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows).

This [git config --system core.longpaths true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26111092/5769938) solution is supposed to fix the issue for me (I have not tried it yet), but... **where** do I place it?

The answer states *"You should be able to run the command... or add it to one of your git config files manually"*  -- which of the git config files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place it on four files (where Jenkins is installed) as described on the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> If not set explicitly with --file, there are four files where git
>   config will search for configuration options:
>
> **$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig**
>
> System-wide configuration file.
>
> **$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config**
>
> Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not
>   set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any single-valued
>   variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in
>   ~/.gitconfig. It is a good idea not to create this file if you
>   sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was
>   added fairly recently.
>
> **~/.gitconfig**
>
> User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration
>   file.
>
> **$GIT_DIR/config**
>
> Repository specific configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely complements my answer, thus accepting and +1.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of anyone having the same question:

After consulting with the [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation, I came to the conclusion that this config change should only be run **once**, using the same git.exe path that is configured in Jenkins:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" config --system core.longpaths true
```

This can be later verified by listing the various settings:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" config -l

core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.longpaths=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
merge.tool=kdiff3
mergetool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
diff.guitool=kdiff3
difftool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
core.editor="C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor
```

There may be other ways, but I only tried this one.

Comment: In my case you have set longpaths before, you should use the --replace-all option: git config --system --replace-all core.longpaths true