# Jenkins job adding DOS newlines to shell scripts, causing a "bad interpreter" error on UNIX

Tags: bash

I am trying to run the following shell script but I am getting the "/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter" error.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf tomcat8/webapps/cpproject*
```

I know that this is happening because I am editing the file on windows and trying to run it on Unix. I tried all the ways of fixing it as suggested on stackoverflow. I tried the following.

1. Installed Vim editor and saved it
2. In Notepad++ changed the End Of Line option to Unix. Tried to save the new documents as Unix format
3. Installed gedit and saved it.
4. Installed doc2unix and tried it.

I tried a lot other ways but nothing worked. Can some one suggest me how to fix this issue?

Updated:

"xxd before_install1.sh | head" command is showing the followng.

```
00000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680a 726d 202d  #!/bin/bash.rm -
00000010: 7266 2074 6f6d 6361 7438 2f77 6562 6170  rf tomcat8/webap
00000020: 7073 2f63 7070 726f 6a65 6374 2a         ps/cpproject*
```

Update:
I made sure that I am not running the old file. Because I changed the file name each time and tried it. I made sure that the new file is being executed each time.
Basically I am using codedeploy jenkins plugin which generates the war file and zips it with scripts and appspec.yml file. Since I change the file name each time and update the appspec.yml file with new name, I am making sure that the new file is being uploaded. But it is giving the same error.
Even after it is uploaded to the S3 bucket I downloaded and the zip file and made sure that it contains the latest one and even executed the xxd command and got the following.

```
$ xxd before_install5.sh | head
00000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680d 0a72 6d20  #!/bin/bash..rm
00000010: 2d72 6620 746f 6d63 6174 382f 7765 6261  -rf tomcat8/weba
00000020: 7070 732f 6370 7072 6f6a 6563 742a 0d0a  pps/cpproject*..
```

Update:

@Charles Duffy, Thank you for your response. I am developing these scripts locally and pushing them to GitHub. I have a Jenkins job, which takes this code from GitHub repository and packages this into a war file. I am using "CodeDeploy" plugin, which will take this war file and zips it with these shell scripts under scripts folder and appspec.yml file and push it to S3 bucket in AWS. The following is what is happening.

xxd command in my local system file:

```
$ xxd before_install5.sh | head
00000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680a 726d 202d  #!/bin/bash.rm -
00000010: 7266 2074 6f6d 6361 7438 2f77 6562 6170  rf tomcat8/webap
00000020: 7073 2f63 7070 726f 6a65 6374 2a0a       ps/cpproject*.
```

xxd command on the file after it is uploaded to GitHub:

```
$ xxd before_install5.sh | head
00000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680a 726d 202d  #!/bin/bash.rm -
00000010: 7266 2074 6f6d 6361 7438 2f77 6562 6170  rf tomcat8/webap
00000020: 7073 2f63 7070 726f 6a65 6374 2a0a       ps/cpproject*.
```

xxd command on the file after it is pulled by Jenkins from GitHub to Local Workspace(in .jenkins/worspace folder)

```
$ xxd before_install5.sh | head
00000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680d 0a72 6d20  #!/bin/bash..rm
00000010: 2d72 6620 746f 6d63 6174 382f 7765 6261  -rf tomcat8/weba
00000020: 7070 732f 6370 7072 6f6a 6563 742a 0d0a  pps/cpproject*..
```

xxd command on the file after it is pushed to s3 bucket in AWS:

```
$ xxd before_install5.sh | head
00000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680d 0a72 6d20  #!/bin/bash..rm
00000010: 2d72 6620 746f 6d63 6174 382f 7765 6261  -rf tomcat8/weba
00000020: 7070 732f 6370 7072 6f6a 6563 742a 0d0a  pps/cpproject*..
```

I am seeing that the extra characters '0d0a' are added after the code is taken by Jenkins into Local Workspace. It's not a problem with CodeDeploy plugin at this momement, it seems. Is there any way we can avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `tr -d '\015'` to delete the carriage return.

Comment: `sed -i 's/\r$//' file` is another way to do it, using GNU sed.

Comment: Tried both of the above but didn't work.

Comment: There is definitely not a `^M` (aka a CR, aka a `$'\r'`) in the file you show the `xxd` dump of in the question. Which is to say, you've successfully removed the faulty character -- are you sure you're _running_ that corrected file, not the original one with the DOS-style newlines?

Comment: BTW, note that UNIX text files have newline **terminators**, not just newline **separators**. Every valid line of text should have a newline after it, _including_ the last one in the file. (This is the other thing that's different between DOS and UNIX text file formats).

Comment: you mean doc2unix or dos2unix?

Comment: `before_install5.sh` has `0d0a` -- aka `\r\n` -- aka CRLF -- aka, it has the problem that `dos2unix` fixes. Compare to your `before_install1.sh` which only has `0a`s (`LF`s) for its newlines, and is thus correct.

Comment: BTW, where are these files coming from? If they're being checked out from a source control system, many revision control systems can be configured as to whether and what kind of newline conversion they do based on which operating system code is being checked out on. So if you're trying to, say, run the file through dos2unix and then check it into git after the change, that may not make any difference, if git itself is configured to convert it to have CRLFs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, updated the question with more details. Can you please check it?

Comment: Reopening this since you added enough details to distinguish it from the previously linked duplicate. Could you add details on _how_ the push to S3 is done? If it's done with this "CodeDeploy" plugin, details on how that plugin is configured might be a place to start. (Also, you might think about _not_ using it, if it's messing up your files).

Comment: Another place to start might be to add some logging in the tools/scripts that call CodeDeploy, to check the files _as they exist in the environment where those scripts run_ immediately before the upload. Just because things look one way in a development environment doesn't necessarily mean they'll exist that way in a production environment, unfortunately.

Comment: (details on how the "after it is uploaded to github" snapshot was taken, in particular, are pertinent; if the path didn't go through the same copy of git that does the checkout pre-deployment, the results may differ depending on configuration).

Comment: ...see f/e the setting `core.autocrlf` documented in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration -- if that's different between your personal system and the CI environment, your results will differ likewise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Sorry! I just did one more check. I verified the file after it is pulled by Jenkins into local workspace and that's where it is adding the DOS line. It's not the problem with CodeDeploy push to S3. So, updated the question heading and description also. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The _easy_ answer here, albeit maybe not the _best_ one, is to have Jenkins run `dos2unix` after the file is already in your workspace.

Comment: Relevant, btw: [For the Jenkins git plugin, where is it recommended to run `git config`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768593/for-the-jenkins-git-plugin-where-is-it-recommended-to-run-git-config)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, looks like dos2unix is working. Have to add the sh executable to jenkins and use the command. But GitHub is down now and will post the solution if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the script is called 'myscript.dos', you can delete the carriage returns with `tr`:

```
tr -d '\015' < myscript.dos > myscript.unix
```

Comment: Tried the above but didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?  Do you mean that `myscript.unix` contains carriage returns, or do you mean that you still cannot executre `myscript.dos`?

Comment: My script is saved as before_install.sh. So I executed the command "tr -d '\015' <before_install.sh> before_install1.sh" and it saved the file before_install1.sh. But when I run the before_install1.sh script on linux machine and I am getting the same error again.

Comment: What does `xxd before_install1.sh | head` show?

Comment: Updated the questions with "$ xxd before_install1.sh | head" results. Please check.

Comment: Your `before_install1.sh` indeed does not have the problem that `tr` was intended to resolve -- presumably meaning the problem _was in fact_ fixed, but you're running the old file that didn't have the fix.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I made sure that I am not running on the old file. Updated the question with details. Please check.

Comment: @Subbu, I've commented on the question.

Answer (score 1):

@Charles Duffy, Thank you for your time and patience in resolving this issue. It is finally working. I am just posting the actual problem and solution here so that it will be useful for other.

Work:
I am working on developing a deployment strategy into AWS using Jenkins and AWS CodeDeploy. I am using CodeDeploy plugin in Jenkins. Jenkins will create a war file and CodeDeploy plugin will create a zip file with the war file, appspec.yml and some shell scripts to stop, start servers etc and this zip file will be pushed to S3 and from there CodeDeploy will be triggered and deploy the war file.

Problem:
The shell scripts used to start the server or stop the server are developed in windows system. So it is adding DOS lines to the scripts so they are not running on Unix in EC2 machines. I have removed the DOS lines on the shell scripts by using different techniques. But since Jenkins is running locally (On Windows Machine), when the code is pulled from GutHub it is again adding DOS lines.

Solution: Please check the above questions and the solutions given by all to find out how to identify if DOS line are being added to shell scripts. Since, in my case,  the DOS lines are added by Jenkins I have to clear them in Jenkins before it is going to produce a zip file.

Go to Jenkins and configure the shell executable first. Since I have git installed on my system, I have a Shell executable in my system.

[image]

Once this is done, go to the Jenkins job created and add "Execute Shell" build step and add the commands shown in the below picture.

[image]

This will remove all the DOS lines added to the scripts and your shell scripts will be executed correctly by codedeploy in AWS on Linux system.

Thank you @Charles Duffy and others who helped me in resolving these issues.

Thank you very much,
Subbu.