# Bit bucket 'This pull request has conflicts' but git locally states 'up-to-date'

Tags: git, web-services, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm having a pretty strange issue with **bit bucket** when I **add a service reference** to a project. In summary, when creating a pull request after adding the service reference, I get a warning, highlighting `This pull request has conflicts.`. So I head to resolve the conflicts, but when running the appropriate commands, I get informed that everything is up to date. Is it possible that git is ignoring certain files which are being picked up in bit bucket? Has anyone had any experience around this area previously?

I'll break it all up in to a bit more detail, highlighting a step by step diagnosis of what I am doing:

1. Add Service Reference to project
2. Commit & Push the changes
3. Create a pull request
4. Bit bucket highlights there are conflicts `You must resolve the conflicts before you can merge`
5. I run the following commands with the following results:

`git fetch origin develop`

`git checkout feature/my-branch`

`git merge FETCH_HEAD`

> Already up-to-date

Any help with this issue would be appreciated as I seem to have hit a dead-end!

**EDIT**

I've narrowed it down further, there are a number of GenericObjectDataSource files added when adding the reference, that have very long file names (just in case there is a max length anyone knows of in bit bucket or git). They look as follows, it's when I check these files in that the conflict message appears:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This file is automatically generated by Visual Studio .Net. It is 
    used to store generic object data source configuration information.  
    Renaming the file extension or editing the content of this file may   
    cause the file to be unrecognizable by the program.
-->
<GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="CreateJobFromResponse" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
   <TypeInfo>Namespace.NamespaceChild.NamespaceGrandChild.NamespaceGreatGrandChild.CreateJobFromResponse, Service References.MyServiceReferences.Reference.cs.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</TypeInfo>
</GenericObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: git fetch dont merge changes to local develop branch. You should merge before checkout to new branch

Comment: The merge has to go through a pull request, it can't be done directly

Comment: of course. You should merge develop branch to your feature branch first

Comment: I get the same message "Already up-to-date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours digging and googling I have finally found the issue. I had an inkling that it may have been related to the length of the file name or path on the server being too long.

It appears that if hosting git on a windows server that by default, the file path cannot exceed 260 characters, unless specifying so in a command.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26111092/67258) that highlighted what was required to fix my issue.

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sequence

```
git checkout develop
git pull --rebase origin develop
git checkout feature/my-branch
git rebase develop
```

Comment: Still the same issue unfortunately, I've narrowed it down to some XML files that are added when adding the reference