# warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed

Tags: github

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>git clone https://github.com/XXXXXXXXXX.git
Cloning into 'one-piece'...
remote: Counting objects: 5463, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3600/3600), done.
remote: Total 5463 (delta 1539), reused 5359 (delta 1438), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5463/5463), 5.08 MiB | 1.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1539/1539), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
warning: unable to access 'hackathon/node_modules/noble/node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket/node_modules/usb
/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/readable-stream/
node_modules/core-util-is/lib/.gitattributes': Filename too long
fatal: cannot create directory at 'hackathon/node_modules/noble/node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket/node_mod
ules/usb/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/readable
-stream/node_modules/process-nextick-args': Filename too long
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: Please ask questions rather than just post the terminal output with relevant warnings. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this out:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

[Source](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/109/how-to-solve-filename-too-long-error-in-git-powershell-and-github-application-for-windows)

Comment: Be careful when doing this, as it can break other things in Windows.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Comment: I am getting `error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied`

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Just open command as Administrator

Answer (score 3):

The following answer worked for me

1. Open either cmd or git bash and run it as an administrator
2. Give the following command on the cmd or git bash which you ran as an administrator above

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

3. This will allow to access long file names globally
4. Now you can clone the repositories without any issue with **Filename too long**

Comment: error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Also check that the repository does not contain a folder called 'con' or 'prn' as these are reserved folders in Windows but are allowed in MacOS.

eg.
src/main/kotlin/con/  will break on a Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is how I solved it:

1. cd into the project directory and un-stage all staged files if any by running git reset
2. undo all changes in the working directory by running git checkout *

After doing the two steps you should be able to see the project files.