# Trying to set file name length limit with git - Permission denied

Tags: git, msysgit

I am trying to clone a GitHub repository containing files with long path names, and I am trying to get around Git's file length restriction using the command

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

However, I am getting the error messages:

```
error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied
error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Invalid argument
```

This seems strange, as the command is trying to change a file in Program Files, not in C:\Users\username where it should be. Furthermore, when I checked C:\Users\username for a .gitconfig file, I was unable to find one. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What do you expect `core.longpaths` to do? I see that the following command, run in the Git repository for Git itself, produces no output at all: `git grep -i longpath`

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Comment: Ah, so this is not a Git thing, but specific to msysgit. I added the msysgit tag; perhaps someone there will know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `git config --global`.

> *This seems strange, as the command is trying to change a file in Program Files, not in C:\Users\username where it should be.*

That is expected behavior. Since you ran `git config --system` it will look for a system-wide config file. From the [`git-config` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)...

> --system
>
> For writing options: write to system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig rather than the repository .git/config.

What you probably want is `git config --global` to write to YOUR global git config file in your user directory. This is in contrast to `git config --local` which is for writing to the current repository's config file in `.git/config`.

> --global
>
> For writing options: write to global ~/.gitconfig file rather than the repository
>              .git/config, write to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config file if this file exists and the
>              ~/.gitconfig file doesn't.

I expect `msysgit` didn't change the behavior of `git config --system`, so it's naively mashing together a Windows style prefix `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64` with a Unix style `/etc/gitconfig` and getting a nonsense path with mixed delimiters.

Consider [letting them know about this behavior](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues) and suggest it be given a better error message.

Answer (score 6):

1. open cmd shell

> as administrator

2. go in program files git
3. run git-bash and change it

`git config --system core.longpaths true`

ps check my gitst about cloning ;) https://gist.github.com/obar1/45175bf22e5c56967b448a666631b21c

Answer (score 0):

Right click on CMD and run it as administrator, then "git config --system core.longpaths true" command will work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).