# Filename too long using git clone

Tags: windows, git, filenames, node-modules

When I clone my Git project I get an error :

> fatal :cannot create directory at 'node_module..': Filename Too long

How can I resolve that?  OS: Windows 10

The folder "node_modules" is on my repository because I need a specific version of NodeJS, I will delete the entire folder from Git later

Comment: See edit for "node_modules". I tried to "git clone" in `C:/` but it doesn't work... My main issue is to get the entire "node_modules" folder from Git.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Kévin. I found [this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows). Does it help with your problem?