# optaplanner (git): filename to long

Tags: git, intellij-idea, filenames, optaplanner

I can't checkout origin/r7.0.0.Beta7 Branch on git https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner.

I get the following error message from Intellij

```
cannot stat 'optaplanner-persistence/optaplanner-persistence-jackson/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/persistence/jackson/api/score/buildin/hardmediumsoftbigdecimal/HardMediumSoftBigDecimalScoreJacksonJsonSerializerAndDeserializerTest.java': Filename too long
```

and the same in my ConEmu Terminal for Windows 7.

```
$ git checkout r7.0.0.Beta7
error: cannot stat 'optaplanner-persistence/optaplanner-persistence-jackson/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/persistence/jackson/api/score/buildin/hardmediumsoftbigdecimal/HardMediumSoftBigDecimalScoreJacksonJsonSerializerAndDeserializerTest.java': Filename too long
```

How I can checkout into the branch or must the developer rename the objects?

Regards 
apvxw

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26111092

Comment: In which directory (full path) did you check it out? How many chars is that full path? Does checking out into `C:\projects\` work?

Comment: My workingdirectory is "/cygdrive/d/Users/apvxw/workspace/github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner" and then I want to pull new commits from github.com, git can't pull some Java Files. Here is one file from  8 files which git want to pull.

optaplanner-persistence/optaplanner-persistence-jackson/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/persistence/jackson/api/score/buildin/hardmediumsoftbigdecimal/HardMediumSoftBigDecimalScoreJacksonJsonDeserializer.java

Comment: I get the same error, when I move the optaplanner directory directly under my c partition on windows "C:\w\o". C = Partition, w = workingdirectory and o = optaplanner