# Fatal error occured while cloning respository from gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, git-clone, git-checkout

when I'm trying to clone using ssh, cloning is succeeded but checkout fails..
Linux guys have no problem with the same operation

[image: Here is my screen]

Any ideas?

Comment: And what does `git status` tell you?

Comment: Shows big list of deleted files and small list of untracked files

Comment: And what the recommended `checkout` command does tell you?

Comment: Anything specific about the files? Windows has some weird restrictions on file names. E.g. a file or dir `com1` could not be created. It could have restricted characters e.g. `:` or  `?`.

Comment: @kan there are not restricted characters, before moving on gerrit I used to work with the same code using git (without gerrit)

Comment: files could have been added recently. Gerrit could not affect checkout anyhow.

Comment: I just ran git checkout and seems there's issue with longer names than allowed in windows.. is there any fix for this?

Comment: Check your disk writing permission, is empty disk space enough?

Comment: The only fix is to not to use long names or Windows. Even if git would be able to create such file names, you may experience similar problems using another tools. Try to checkout into a shorter name folder e.g. "C:\my\"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filename too long in git for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)