# While cloning a repository using GitHub Desktop, I'm facing 'Filename is too long' error

Tags: github, clone, github-for-windows

Unable to clone my repository from GitHub using GitHub Desktop application.

'Filename is too long' error thrown at final moment of cloning.

Anyone Please help to set up my repository.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), and, as mentioned in "[Filename too long in git for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22575662/6309)"

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Then try to clone again.

The alternative would be to use a `subst Y: C:\path\to\arent\folder`, switch to the `Y:` drive, and clone from there. But with recent msys2 shell, that should not be needed anymore.