# "Filename too long" error in Jenkins git checkout

Tags: git, jenkins

Git checkout in Jenkins throws the error "Filename too long" and fails, as follows:

> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe checkout -f 2cea7d8eb9185899c01d2ffc86872f584da2e60c" returned status code 1:
>
> stdout:
> stderr: error: unable to create file
> *some_long_named_project*/src/test/resources/dbunit_test_data/com/*some_long_named_directory*/data/testInstances_create_dataRequiresData.xml:
> Filename too long

I've set the longpaths variable in the config file to 'true', as suggested here [Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows) and here https://sifaserdarozen.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/git-file-name-too-long-error/, but it didn't help.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 18):

In order for Git to handle long filenames correctly, `core.longpaths=true` needs to be enabled. To set this argument you can do the following:

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

Comment: "Prepare an environment for the run" checkbox in Jenkins job configuration adds pre-checkout steps

Comment: @klapshin I see that section, but where and how would this get added in that?

Answer (score 6):

[This answer by Saikat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49080763/5170571) worked for me to fix this issue for a Jenkins git checkout.

> **Steps to follow (Windows):**
>
> 1. Run **Git Bash** as **administrator**
> 2. Run the following command:
>
> `git config --system core.longpaths true`
>
> **Note:** if step 2 does not work or gives any error, you can also try running this
> command:
>
> `git config --global core.longpaths true`
>
> Read more about `git config` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

(EDIT: Note that there's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813054/5170571) which suggests to apply the setting specifically to the affected project rather than using the `--system` or `--global` flags.)

Answer (score 5):

If you run Windows 10 Home Edition you could change you Registry to enable Long Paths.

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` in `regedit` and then set `LongPathsEnabled` to `1`.

If you have Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise you could also use Local Group Policies.

Go to `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem` in `gpedit.msc`, open `Enable Win32 long paths` and set it to `Enabled`.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround I defined a virtual drive for WORKSPACE path in jenkinsfile script:

```
bat 'subst W: /d || exit 0' //delete the virtual drive if it already exists 
bat 'subst W: "%WORKSPACE%"'
```

and later delete it:

```
bat 'subst W: /d'
```