# git clone command issue with long path

Tags: git

I am using git clone command

```
git clone <repo_url> <moveToDirectory>.
```

This command is working fine if `moveToDirectory` length is short, But if `moveToDirectory` length is long (i.e a with more folders), then this command is not working.

How can I use `git clone` in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved by using this solution

[Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

The solution above did not work with git 1.17... version of git therefore I needed to upgrade my git to the latest version.

Comment: Yes, my solution if for Git 2.0+

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using the syntax:

```
git -C /long/path/to/parent/folder clone <url> directoryName
```

That will force Git to cd into the long path first, then clone to the folder.