# Unable to checkout Mule code due to file name too long issue

Tags: git, mule, mule-esb

i am facing issue when trying to download the runtime codebase from git.  This is due to the file name check probably the absolute package + file name is quite lengthy one.

Any idea how to resolve this.  This is blocking to checkout the code, fyi - i am trying to download under my C:/ directory only.

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule

**ERROR**

```
error: unable to create file modules/deployment-model-impl/src/test/resources/domains/plugin-dependency-with-additional-dependencies-heavyweight/repository/org/mule/tests/test-dependant-plugin/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/test-dependant-plugin-4.2.0-SNAPSHOT-mule-plugin.jar: Filename too long
Checking out files: 100% (4829/4829), done.
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: Hi, are you under windows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Comment: Great Thanks.  git config --system core.longpaths true - solution fixed the issue.