# I'm unable to sync my code directly from VS 2017 team explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, synchronization, team-explorer

I'm working on VS 2017(windows version), in a small development team. When I commit my code using team-explorer, and want to sync my code, get the following error.

"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)

Comment: PavelAnikhouski, Thanks but the answers to that question not solved my problem