# GitKraken where is the .gitconfiguration file to enable Long Paths

Tags: git, gitkraken

To now I have used Git from the Command Line Runner and from GitHub Desktop.

I tried to use GitKraken ,but there is one really big issue with it. I have repository, which has really nested folders, which exceed the 256 length.This problem is easy resolvable with Git and GitHub Desktop, because you go to `.gitconfig` and add under the core section - `longpaths = true`.

The problem is I cant find the `.gitconfig` file that GitKraken is using and so I cant disable the longpaths and clone my repository via GitKraken.

I have two questions:

1. How to enable long paths for GitKraken so I can clone my repository?
2. Where is the .gitconfig file that GitKraken is using?

Comment: I have run into the same issues using GitKraken. I found a config file in the repository in the hidden folder .git/ and added longpaths = true in the [core] section, but this did not fix the problem. In the end I switched to a different application.

Comment: I switched the same day to Sourcetree and I have no intensions to back to GitKraken

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the [January 2020 GitKraken 6.5](https://blog.axosoft.com/gitkraken-v6-5-fork-perf-improvements/). It includes:

> ### GitKraken Supports Longpaths for Windows
>
> GitKraken now supports longpaths for Windows users.
>
> You must set up this feature through the Preferences window.
> Simply click the checkbox next to `Longpaths` and you will be ready to go.

[image: longpaths in GitKraken -- https://blog.axosoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/longpaths.gif]

That means:

> GitKraken now supports `core.longpaths`, making it possible for Windows users to work with long paths exceeding 259 characters in length.

Comment: Added the same, also updated the [Registry Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575737/6623589) still getting the same error. Any idea? However, I am not facing any errors from Git Bash.

Comment: @Mr.Hobo It would be preferable to check your particular use case in a separate question, specifying your exact version of your OS, Git and GitKraken.

Comment: Please check the details in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74399172/6623589) @VonC