# Filename too Long in GitKraken for Windows

Tags: windows, git, gitkraken, long-path

As suggested in [Q22575737](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575737/6623589), I've updated my registry and have set `git config --system core.longpaths true` while working with long paths. The problem is solved in [Git Bash for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) however, I am getting the error in GitKraken as below. I've also enabled `Long Paths = True` from GitKraken preferences as suggested in [Q60008822](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008822/6623589)

[image]

Related information to OS and file system:

```bash
debmalya@DESKTOP-IPD20NF MINGW64 ~
$ git --version
git version 2.38.1.windows.1

GitKraken Client Version: 8.10.3 (x64)

Windows Specifications
======================
Edition Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version         22H2
Installed on    ‎02-‎11-‎2022
OS build        19045.2130
Experience      Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0
```

`.gitconfig` file settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try and [map a local folder to a drive letter](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2694895/how-to-map-a-local-folder-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows.html)

```
subst x: C:\your`\long\path\to\root\folder\of\repository
```

See if the issue persists when opening X:\ as your repository in GitKraken.

Comment: Fails with the message: `Open Failed: Could not find a compatible repository at 'gitkraken.exe'`, but  `git bash` recognizes it.

Comment: @Mr.Hobo Did you map the root folder of your repository? (and not a subfolder inside the repo)

Comment: My long path is `D:\dev-works\<repository-root>\subdir\subdir\subdir\<submodule-folder>` I tried with both repository root and submodule folder, got the same result ([repository-link](https://github.com/ZenithClown/self-development/tree/master/Learning%20Platforms/Coursera%20Inc/Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms%20Specialization%20%5BUC%20San%20Diego%5D/Course%202%20-%20Data%20Structures))

Comment: @Mr.Hobo OK. I was suggesting to subst only to `D:\dev-works\<repository-root>\`, not below. That might not be enough.