# How do I fix CalledProcessError problem with precommit and hook prospector?

Tags: python, githooks, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

details:
-Python 3.7.5
-Precommit 2.6.0
-prospector 1.1.7
-VScode editor

I have a problem with the hook **prospector**.I have installed **pre-commit** using pip, and when I use its CLI without hook **prospector** in the config .yaml, everything goes fine:

```
(env) C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\solution>pre-commit run --all-files
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
Check Yaml...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check for added large files..............................................Passed
Check python ast.........................................................Passed
Check JSON...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check for case conflicts.................................................Passed
Check for merge conflicts................................................Passed
Detect Private Key.......................................................Passed
Debug Statements (Python)................................................Passed
Mixed line ending........................................................Passed
mypy.....................................................................Passed
```

finally when I append the hook prospector in the last four lines at the **.pre-commit-config.yaml** as it's shown bellow:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v2.4.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
    -   id: check-ast
    -   id: check-json
    -   id: check-case-conflict
    -   id: check-merge-conflict
    -   id: detect-private-key
    -   id: debug-statements
    -   id: mixed-line-ending
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: 'v0.782'  # Use the sha / tag you want to point at
    hooks:
    -   id: mypy
-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/prospector
    rev: "1.1.7" # The version of Prospector to use, at least 1.1.7
    hooks:
    -   id: prospector
```

when I run it again, show the next message:

```
    (env) C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\solution>pre-commit run --all-files
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/PyCQA/prospector.
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.EXE', 'checkout', '1.1.7')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout: (none)
stderr:
    error: cannot stat 'tests/finder/testdata/venvs/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv/long_path_not_a_venv': Filename too long
    error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .coveragerc
        .gitignore
        .pre-commit-config.yaml
        .pre-commit-hooks.yaml
        .prospector.yml
        .travis.yml
        CHANGELOG.md
        CONTRIBUTORS.md
        LICENSE
        MANIFEST.in
        README.rst
        docs/Makefile
        docs/conf.py
        docs/contrib.rst
        docs/index.rst
        docs/profiles.rst
        docs/requirements.txt
        docs/supported_tools.rst
        docs/suppression.rst
        docs/usage.rst
        prospector/__init__.py
        prospector/__main__.py
        prospector/__pkginfo__.py
        prospector/autodetect.py
        prospector/blender.py
        prospector/blender_combinations.yaml
        prospector/config/__init__.py
        prospector/config/configuration.py
        prospector/config/datatype.py
        prospector/encoding.py
        prospector/exceptions.py
        prospector/finder.py
        prospector/formatters/__init__.py
        prospector/formatters/base.py
        prospector/formatters/emacs.py
        prospector/formatters/grouped.py
        prospector/formatters/json.py
        prospector/formatters/pylint.py
        prospector/formatters/text.py
        prospector/formatters/vscode.py
        prospector/formatters/xunit.py
        prospector/formatters/yaml.py
        prospector/message.py
        prospector/pathutils.py
        prospector/postfilter.py
        prospector/profiles/__init__.py
        prospector/profiles/profile.py
        prospector/profiles/profiles/default.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/doc_warnings.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/flake8.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/full_pep8.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/member_warnings.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/no_doc_warnings.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/no_member_warnings.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/no_pep8.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/no_test_warnings.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/strictness_high.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/strictness_low.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/strictness_medium.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/strictness_none.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/strictness_veryhigh.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/strictness_verylow.yaml
        prospector/profiles/profiles/test_warnings.yaml
        prospector/run.py
        prospector/suppression.py
        prospector/tools/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/base.py
        prospector/tools/dodgy/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/frosted/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/mccabe/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/mypy/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/pep257/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/pep8/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/profile_validator/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/pyflakes/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/pylint/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/pylint/collector.py
        prospector/tools/pylint/indent_checker.py
        prospector/tools/pylint/linter.py
        prospector/tools/pyroma/__init__.py
        prospector/tools/utils.py
        prospector/tools/vulture/__init__.py
        setup.py
        tests/__init__.py
        tests/config/__init__.py
        tests/config/test_datatype.py
        tests/finder/__init__.py
        tests/finder/test_file_finder.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test1/package1/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test1/somedir/package2/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test2/module.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test2/package/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test2/package/subpackage/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test3/package/a/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test3/package/b/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test3/package/c/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/test3/package/d/__init__.py
        tests/finder/testdata/venvs/is_a_venv/Scripts/README.txt
        tests/finder/testdata/venvs/is_a_venv/bin/README.txt
        tests/finder/testdata/venvs/is_a_venv/include/README.txt
        tests/finder/testdata/venvs/is_a_venv/lib/README.txt
    Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
    Aborting

Check the log at C:\Users\Manuel\.cache\pre-commit\pre-commit.log
```

What do I have to do in order to fix this?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it looks like they have a test data file which exceeds the file length limit on windows -- perhaps [try enabling long paths](https://superuser.com/q/1119883)?

Comment: I actually have windows 7, any similar solution for this version?

Comment: yeah, I'd suggest googling how to enable long paths in windows 7, it's similar but different

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on Windows 10.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575737/692665) helps me to solve the problem.

In short, you can allow a long path using Git config like this:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```