# Unable to deploy react application to github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, web-applications, github-pages

I am trying to deploy a simple react application, it worked the first time, but when i updated my code to github repo and tried to run 'npm run deploy', it failed

[image: Error in deployment]

Below is my package.json

[image: Package.json]

I am new to react and deploying apps to server

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use the latest version of npm, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477534/6309), and in [`npm/npm` issue 7768](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7768)

Second, looking at the history of your [`AJ555/react-exp`, `gh-pages` branch](https://github.com/AJ555/react-exp/commits/gh-pages), start by reverting the last two commit (to get back to the state where the first deployment succeeded), and check if it is still working.

If it does work, then the issue is in the current last two commits.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well. What I do is restart my computer and then try run `npm run deploy` again.