# Organize git repo to avoid running into 'filename too long' issue

Tags: windows, git

I use git submodules in my repositories often. These submodules can themselves be several levels deep with other submodules. This often results in the filename too long issue on Windows. I have enabled long path support both on Windows and on git (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)). i.e. if I run the following commands:

`git config --global --get core.longpaths`

`git config --system --get core.longpaths`

I get true.

`LongPathsEnabled` is also set to `1` under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`

After scouring the internet, I've learned long paths should be avoided in the first place (e.g. [see this link](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2/issues/157)).

So my main question is: what is the "correct way" of organizing repositories that depend on other repositories without running into the long path issue?

In my case, the repositories are usually .NET projects that depend on other libraries (included as submodules), these libraries further depend on other libraries and so forth.

Like so:

Project A --> submodule A --> submodule B --> submodule C --> submodule D...

I was also wondering whether I'm enabling the long path support correctly?

Comment: You probably just want to extract the submodules into their own packages, and mark them as dependencies. See [Manage Dependencies in .NET Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dependencies)