# `git restore --source=HEAD :/` does not work after cloning repo with long file names failed

Tags: git, git-for-windows

On Windows when I try to clone a repository which contains files with long paths (e.g. [this repository](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core)) it fails:
[image: Git error]

My question is not how to solve this (that is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22575662)), but about the command it recommends:

```
git restore --source=HEAD :/
```

When I run `git config core.longpaths true` followed by that command it has no effect: The command takes a while but afterwards `git status` still reports a lot of changes.

However, running `git reset --hard` works without issues and properly checks out the files.

So is Git's advice of using `git restore` incorrect (at least in this context)?

---

Git version: 2.33.0.windows.2

Answer (score 1):

> When I run `git config core.longpaths true` followed by [the recommended `git restore`] command it has no effect: The command takes a while but afterwards `git status` still reports a lot of changes.  However, running `git reset --hard` works without issues and properly checks out the files.

This implies a bug in Git-for-Windows.  The bug might be quite difficult to fix (basically Git has no idea how `core.longpaths` was set on an earlier attempt), but you should report it.

You can try `git restore --source=HEAD -SW :/`, which makes the action match `git reset --hard` internally, and see if that works.  If it does, perhaps the fix will be to change the default advice here. :-)

Comment: Created a report for it: [#3411](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3411)

Comment: The report eventually moved to the Git mailing list: https://public-inbox.org/git/07ae9b61a42346a0b49744586d4496bd@vodafonemail.de/T/#u