# I get a deploy error on Windows with "npm run build"

Tags: reactjs, npm-run

I got this error when I was running the `npm run deploy` command in the terminal, how can I resolve this error?

[image: Error image]

Comment: I think this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this link will help you:

[Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)

You must run this command in your terminal:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Comment: Wow, this works thank you so much, initially i didn't believe that this will work but this resolved the problem thanks again

Comment: If you find an exact duplicate, it is best just to flag the question as a dup, rather than answering.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer section.)*

1. Run Git Bash as administrator (right-clicking the app shortcut will show the option to Run as Administrator )
2. Run the following command: `git config --system core.longpaths true`

Note: if step 2 does not work or gives any error, you can also try running this command: `git config --global core.longpaths true`

This worked for me.