# git status "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Tags: git-clone, git-status

I am collaborating with my teammates on a Project in which one of my teammate has uploaded our project on GitHub.

I want to clone the repository into my VS Code.

Here are the steps I have performed:

1. I clicked the "Fork" button on the top right corner of my teammate's repository.
2. Then I go to "Your Repositories" and clicked the repository in which I have forked just now.
3. Then I clicked the Green Button "Code" and copied the URL of my repository.
4. Next, I go to my VS Code and typed `git clone <URL>` in which the URL is the URL that I have just copied.
5. Then my VS Code Terminal shows this long message:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWKmo.png)

6. Then when I run `git status`, the output is `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` as you can see at the bottom of the screenshot.

May I know did I do any mistakes? What are the correct steps to rectify the issues displayed by the Terminal? Thank you.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Answer (score 2):

You need to be present in the active directory in which the git repository was cloned.

cd into the downloaded directory then VS Code will automatically get updated with the current repo.

Try using extensions like Git lens and other git-related extensions that make this process easier.

Comment: May I know how to perform `cd into the downloaded directory`?

Comment: In the command line/ Powershell terminal type 
`cd <your-directory-name>` . In your case it should be
`cd student-course-registration-system` . Another note: Seems like your git checkout process has failed when I looked closely into your screenshot.
Could be a network error or the Repository is not correctly maintained. Try git cloning again then change the active directory using cd as shown above.

Comment: I have tried running `cd student-course-registration-system` and when I run `git status` again, my Terminal shows this result: [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/VDTQj2N) . May I know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried running cd student-course-registration-system and when I run git status again, my Terminal shows this result:

[image: https://ibb.co/VDTQj2N]

As mentioned in the screenshot, use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore):

```
git restore --staged --worktree -- .
```

That will restore all files from HEAd commit to your working tree and index.

Answer (score 0):

Just check are you in correct directory where you have cloned project. Then run below command to pull code

git pull -r

if this is not working check in your current directory has .git file. If it's not there it's not a git directory you have check and clone again.

And also try go into next directory from current directory and run the same command.

git pull -r

It may be a git directory but you tried out side of that parent directory.