# Issue while cloning BotBuilder-Samples GitHub repository

Tags: node.js, git, botframework, microsoft-teams

I tried to clone the [BotBuilder repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/06.using-cards) but it gives the following error:

```
fatal: cannot create directory at
'composer-samples/csharp_dotnetcore/pipelines/CICDPipelineSample/BasicAssistant/BasicAssistant/dialogs/imported/Microsoft.Bot.Components.HelpAndCancel/CancelDialog/knowledge-base':
Filename too long warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. You
can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry with 'git
restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [260 character max path limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation)

Check first if a [`git config --global core.longpaths true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71775890/6309) helps.

Check if you can implement [some of the remediation](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/), although it is not clear how a "Microsoft Team" environment would influence that.

Comment: git config --global core.longpaths true worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DummyCron Great, well done.