# Win10 update, now GIT does not 'see' files with long paths

Tags: git, windows-10

After I did an OS update of my windows 10, I am now facing the problem that Git sees some paths as 'to be deleted':

```
$ git status
On branch feature/TEST-1
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/TEST-1'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    /super-long-path/part-00001-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
        deleted:    /super-long-path/part-00002-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
        deleted:    /super-long-path/part-00006-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
        deleted:    /super-long-path/part-00007-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
```

But the files are there:

```
$ ls -1
/super-long-path/part-00001-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
/super-long-path/part-00002-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
/super-long-path/part-00006-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
/super-long-path/part-00007-bef3dabd-0544-4a0c-a1e7-c3df267e616d_00000.snappy.parquet
```

The issue is basically that Gits no longer sees files which have too long paths.
Someone suggested running the following command but it did not help me: `git config --system  core.longpaths true`
and yes I have applied it globally and also running the GIT shell as administrator, did not help.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

The only temp solution i have found so far is to tell git to ignore those files: `git update-index --assume-unchanged ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)

Comment: @Eng_Farghly no, most of the answers there point to the attempted solution i have mentioned in my post `git config --system  core.longpaths true` but is not working in my case