# git diff "Filename too long"

Tags: git, github

The filename given to `git diff` is 76 characters long.

```
aaaa/bbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.json
```

The concatenated files line is 254 characters long.

```
origin/BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:aaaa/bbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.json..origin/BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:aaaa/bbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.json
```

Execution of the `git diff` command produces:

```
git diff --ignore-cr-at-eol --exit-code origin/BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:aaaa/bbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.json..origin/BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:aaaa/bbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.json
fatal: failed to stat 'origin/BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:aaaa/bbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.json..origin/BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:aaaa/bbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.json': Filename too long
```

Environment:

```
Caption             : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version             : 10.0.19044
DisplayVersion      : 21H2
```

Comment: What O/S are you on?

Comment: Running Windows 10

Comment: Windows I bet. Git hasn't quite figured out long path names in Windows like the rest of the world.

Comment: On Windows the `:` character is not a legal file name character.

Comment: @stdunbar, I thought that the COLON character was part of the `git diff` syntax separating `origin/branch` from the filename.

Comment: That's weird because it is interpreting the 2 files you want to compare as if they were a single file. What happens if you enclose it in single or double quotes?

Comment: @lit what you are trying to do is correct: `branch1:some-file..branch2:another-file`.

Comment: @eftshift0, same result using QUOTATION MARK characters. I am also specifying `origin/branch`. Is that a problem?

Comment: Nope, that should not be a problem. Does it also fail if you try on a linux box?

Comment: @eftshift0, would that I could try it on a Linux box. Not available.

Comment: What is your question about this error?

Comment: The filename is only 76 characters long. Is git really limited to 76 character file names? Is this a limit of `git diff`? Is there any docmentation on file name length limits?

Comment: _technically_ there isn't a question in your post, I imagine you are asking how to fix this issue. See for example : https://stackoverflow.com/q/22575662/86072 . Found by searching the error message in the search box : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Filename+too+long

Comment: @LeGEC, yes, the question is how to make it work. That is why we are here on SO. Right? It appears that using `git config --system core.longpaths true` made it work. I have done limited testing. It might be helpful if this failure is encountered and running on Windows, that a message about core.longpaths should be emitted.